# Method shapely.intersection returns a wrong answer

Tags: python, geometry, shapely

I try to find intersection of two edges in 2D using method shapely.intersection and get a wrong answer
Shapely module v.2.0.1

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString
a = LineString([[30.0,0.0],[36.0,30.0]])
b = LineString([[32.8,14.0],[35.2,26.0]])
intersection = a.intersection(b)
```

It is easy to check that edge `b` entirely lays on edge `a`, and so the result of intersection will be equals `b`
but code returns one point (the center of the edge `b`)
`Point(34,20)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is the result of imperfect precision in floating point math. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) discusses the topic extensively.

[`shapely.intersection`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.intersection.html) gives you the option to specify a grid size to limit the precision of the calculations:

```py
> shapely.intersection(a, b, 0.1)
<MULTILINESTRING ((32.8 14, 34 20), (34 20, 35.2 26))>
```

The returned `MultiLineString` consists of multiple segements (I haven't looked into why). You can use the [`oriented_envelope`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.MultiLineString.html#shapely.MultiLineString.oriented_envelope) property of the returned `MultiLineString` to reduce the connected segments back into a single `LineString` (as long as they are actually connected and colinear):

```py
> line_string = shapely.intersection(a, b, 0.1)
> line_string.oriented_envelope
<LINESTRING (32.8 14, 35.2 26)>
```

Comment: thank you, your solution works well, I've tried to change parameter `grid_size` but I setted too  low value - about 1e-9

Comment: One comment has appeared - after adding `grid_size` = 0.1 `intersection` returns `b` as 2 edges `<MULTILINESTRING ((32.8 14, 34 20), (34 20, 35.2 26))>`. Is it possible to get whole edge `b`?

Comment: Edited to add how you can combine segments

Comment: But why does method `intersects` not have parameter `grid_size`? In my code I am trying to check  does `A` intersect `B` or not and then I will find the intersection. But how to do this if methods`intersects` and `intersection` have the different precision ?

Comment: I don't know. It does seem like `intersects` taking a `grid_size` option would be useful. You'd probably need to ask the original authors to be sure.